# What is the area of the shaded region? (Overlapping areas)

Tags: mathematics, geometry

[image: Picture describing the puzzle]
What is the area of the region poly1 formed by the arcs 'cdke'. The square is of sides 10 units long. The region poly1 is formed by four overlapping quadrants.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this is puzzling.se This question can't be solved purely mathematically. I mean given a square of length 10 I can draw many different arcs cdke such that the inner area is anything from almost everything to almost nothing.

Comment: I assume the arcs are quarter circles centered on the respective corners of the square?

Comment: @Yanko can't it be solved with the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess this is the idea, but right now you need some more assumptions about the question. Perhaps with SteveV's extra assumption it is possible to solve this question.

Comment: ...oh I thought that was #obvious# especially as they are called "quadrants" and there is presumably one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

Notation:
[image: notation]

Step 1:

> Adding the four quadrants would render
>  2(I+III+VII+IX) + 3*(II+IV+VI+VIII) + 4*V = pi*10*10

Step 2:

> Minus 2 10*10 square from both sides:
>  1*(II+IV+VI+VIII) + 2*V = 100(pi-2)

Step 3:

> II+V+VIII = pi*10*10/2 - 10*10 = 100(pi/2-1)
>  (2 quadrants minus square)